# How to upload multiple documents with multiple JSON files to Cloudant DB via node js?

Tags: json, node.js, api, couchdb, cloudant

Currently, I have a requirement to reprocess the failure records that sit in the Cloudant DB ex.say fail DB. I need to take records from there for a particular day, say 20 records, and place them in Reprocess DB. Can you please help me how to bulk insert 20 failure records that can be stored as 20 different JSON Files using Node JS.

Sample request:

```
{
  "docs": [

    {
        "_id": "XXX",
        "_rev": "1-XXX",
        "timestamp": "2018-01-06T14:36:09.834Z",
        "DocType": "CustFail",
        "RequestPayload": {

        },
        "CustID": "4",
        "Response": "Fail"
    },
    {
        "_id": "XXX",
        "_rev": "1-XXX",
        "timestamp": "2018-01-06T14:36:09.834Z",
        "DocType": "CustFail",
        "RequestPayload": {

        },
        "CustID": "42",
        "Response": "Fail"
    }


  ]
}
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the [`nodejs-cloudant`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cloudant) library, you should be able to call [`bulk()`](https://github.com/cloudant-labs/cloudant-nano#dbbulkdocs-params-callback) passing in the array of JSON docs to be inserted